# .htaccess doesn't recognize allowed ips

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

we're facing a strange problem on our dev-site.
We have a magento installation running on that dev-site which is only accessible by our company-owned ip.

A few days ago we got a faster internet connection and a new external ip, so we changed the ip in our htaccess-file.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "x.x.x.1" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "x.x.x.2" AllowIP
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "x.x.x.3" AllowIP
Allow from env=AllowIP
```

We only changed the ip at the "`Set envIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "x.x.x.x" AllowIP` "-Part of the htaccess.

The rest of the htaccess was left untouched, but if we try do access the dev-Site we get always redirected to our live-Site.
The second dev-site on the same server runs perfectly with exactly the same changes and can be access without problems.

First we thought it was a problem regarding varnish cache, so we put the "Set envIF"-Part before the deny,allow part of the file as it was mentioned in some troubleshooting posts.
But it didn't helped.

So can anybody gives us a hint what we are doing wrong?

**EDIT 23.11.2015:**

We've found the problem. In the index-page of the affected site there's a php script checking which ip the client uses when he enters the site.
And there was the old ip entered so that the script blocked us, no after putting the correct ip into the script all works as it should.

Thanks you all for your help!

Best regards
tireniets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only allow certain IP Address you can use this in your .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 1.2.3.4   </Limit>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. 
We've tried it, but no chance...if we call the url of auf dev-site we're redirected to our live-site. :/

It's very strange...the other dev-site on the same server with the exact same settings in the .htaccess works fine.

I have the feeling, that i'm overseeing something...